# Lightning dashboard subscriptions

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am getting only a few Roles. Not all Roles while subscribing dashboard using "Roles and Subordinates".

From Lightning Dashboard, there is an option to set up the Edit Recipient. In the Edit Recipient, there is an option to select "Roles and Subordinates". After selecting this option, I am getting only a few roles. Not all roles.

Answer (score 0):

To get the roles in the list the user has to first select required roles from “Dashboard Folders”. The steps are given below. Also, please find the attachment for the same.
1.  Go to “Dashboard” list view.
2.  Go to “All Folders”. Search the required Dashboard folder. Click on the “Share” option from the required dashboard folder.
3.  Once Share Folder Popup opens, from the “Share with” list, select “Roles and Subordinates”. Next, from the “Names” field select the required Role. Then click on the “Share” button and then click on the “Done”.
4.  Newly Added “Roles and Subordinates” will get reflected in the Dashboard (which are under the above-shared dashboard folder).
Note: The user can remove “Users”, “Roles” and “Roles and Subordinates” from the “Share” option. The same will get reflected in the dashboard subscribe setting.